# How to import XenServer's ovf/ova/xva format to KVM?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, xenserver, import, ovf

Now I'm considering migrate from Xen to KVM. I exported some exist virtual machines from Xen in the formats `ovf` and `xva`. How could I import them into KVM?

As there're only a few of virtual machines, I would accept a manual way.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a straight quote from the Red Hat 6 help link, in case it fails. It seems everything is based on using virt-v2v now, and doing an offline xva to kvm isn't so simple. Try the virt-v2v man pages.

```
virt-v2v -ic qemu+ssh://root@vmhost.example.com/system -op pool --bridge bridge_name  guest_name
```

Where vmhost.example.com is the host running the virtual machine, pool is the local storage pool to hold the image, bridge_name is the name of a local network bridge to connect the converted virtual machine's network to, and guest_name is the name of the Xen virtual machine.

You may also use the --network parameter to connect to a locally managed network if your virtual machine only has a single network interface. If your virtual machine has multiple network interfaces, edit /etc/virt-v2v.conf to specify the network mapping for all interfaces.

If your virtual machine uses a Xen para-virtualized kernel (it would be called something like kernel-xen or kernel-xenU) virt-v2v will attempt to install a new kernel during the conversion process. You can avoid this requirement by installing a regular kernel, which will not reference a hypervisor in its name, alongside the Xen kernel prior to conversion. You should not make this newly installed kernel your default kernel, because Xen will not boot it. virt-v2v will make it the default during conversion.

[Instructions for Red Hat 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/subsect-convert-a-remote-xen-virtual-machine.html)
[Instructions for Red Hat 7](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1353783)

Comment: in Debian / Ubuntu - `apt install libguestfs-tools`

Comment: In Gentoo, install `app-emulation/libguestfs`